# How I get color hex value from an Imager::Color object?

Tags: perl

If I use [Imager::Color](https://metacpan.org/pod/Imager::Color) and define a color object like:

```
$color = Imager::Color->new($red, $green, $blue, $alpha);
```

How can I get the hex-value from `$color`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ignores the alpha value, but using the [`rgba`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Imager%3A%3AColor#rgba()) method from [Imager::Color](https://metacpan.org/pod/Imager%3A%3AColor) you can can convert it like this:

```
my $hex_color = sprintf '#%02x%02x%02x', ($color->rgba)[0 .. 2];
```

That pulls the first three fields returned from `$color->rgba` and formats them as two-digit hex values.

```
use Imager;
my $color = Imager::Color->new(64, 250, 150, 1);
say sprintf('#%02x%02x%02x', ($color->rgba)[0 .. 2]);
# → #40fa96
```